# how to test a .7z archive is password protected from command line?

Tags: powershell, extract, 7zip

I'm writing a piece of powershell code to wrap the 7z.exe command line utility. Let's say I have a list of 7z archives and I want to pass the default password to 7z.exe if the archive is password protected and does not pass the password if it's not password protected. I need to way to find whether the 7z archive need a password. How to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not error to specify a password for unprotected archives. So, just pass it for every archive.